# Processing 3 executable not running when adding sound library

Tags: python, processing

I am making an application that requires sound in the python environment of Processing 3. When I add the library and implement the sound, everything works fine in development. When I export the file to an exe, it only loads as far as the splash screen then stops. When I comment out the audio lines, it compiles the exe and works fine.

```
add_library('minim')
minim = Minim(this)   

 def setup():
       size(800, 600)
       player = minim.loadFile("audio.mp3")
       player.play()
```

Is there a known work around for this issue? It seems documentation for python is lacking. Tons of resources for java. I'd hate to have to convert my entire code to java just to have the option of sound.